# 'GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAdsDefines.h' file not found

Tags: admob, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I was building my project(`objc-swift` both using, deployment Target 8.1, Xcode7 beta6) and it includes Google Admob.

[image: build log]

Like above, it fails with those errors.

I imported the GoogleMobileAds into my swift file.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds
```

[image: linked frameworks and libraries]

This is `linked frameworks and libraries` in my project

I did(or checked)

- clean(command shift k)
- clear Derived Data folder
- reboot both pc and iphone.

Any Idea? ㅜㅜ

Comment: Did you every fix this problem?  If so please can you add comments or answer as I have the same issue.

Comment: I just moved to another ad publisher. So I cant make any comments or answer. Sorry ㅜㅜ